# how do i get information passed between the subroutines while using tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Basically, I want to access and use the variables in the `mainlogin` function, from the `loginbuttonclicked`.

```
def mainlogin():

    screen4 = Tk()
    screen4.geometry('600x400')
    screen4.title('the main menu')
    screen4.bg = 'red'
    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    label_username = Label(text="Username")
    label_password = Label(text="Password")

    username_mainlogin_entry = Entry(textvariable=username_verify)
    password__mainlogin_entry = Entry(textvariable=password_verify, show="*")

    label_username.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
    label_password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
    username_mainlogin_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    password__mainlogin_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)


    checkbox = Checkbutton(text="Keep me logged in")
    checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)
    checkbox = Checkbutton(text='New user', command=newuserbtn)
    checkbox.grid(columnspan=3)
    checkbox = Checkbutton(text='override', command=mainprogram)
    checkbox.grid(columnspan=4)


    logbtn = Button(text="Login", command=loginbtnclicked)
    logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)


def loginbtnclicked():

    username_entry = StringVar()
    password_entry = StringVar()
    username = username_entry.get()
    password = username_entry.get()

    if username == 'a' and password == 'p':
        mainprogram()

    else:
        print('oh')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to restructure your code to achieve that.

You either use `global` variables or you use a `class` structure.

1. Global variable:

   ```
   def mainlogin():
       global var_to_access
       var_to_access=10

   def loginbtnclicked():
       print(var_to_access)
   ```
2. Class structure:

   ```
   class My_Class:
       def __init__():
           pass

       def mainlogin():
           self.var_to_access=10

       def loginbtnclicked():
           print(self.var_to_access)
   ```